# A minimal eigenvalue inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric positive definite matrix. Let $A^{(-1)}_{i,j}$ be the $n\times n$ matrix the entries $(i,i),\,(i,j),\,(j,i),\,(j,j)$ of which equal to the corresponding entries of the inverse of the row $i$ column $j$ principal minor of $A$, and all other entries zero. Let me put the verbal defintion in the last sentence into more sepcific terms. Let $a_{ij}$ be the $(i,j)$ entry of $A$. Let $C_{i,j}$ be the $2\times2$ matrix $C_{i,j} :=\begin{bmatrix}a_{ii} & a_{ij} \\ a_{ij} & a_{jj}\end{bmatrix}$, which is the row $i$ column $j$ principal minor of $A$. Let $\big[C_{i,j}^{-1}\big]_{kl},\,k,l\in\{1,2\}$ be the $(k,l)$ entry of the inverse of $C_{i,j}$. Then the $(p,q), \,p,q\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ entry of $A^{(-1)}_{i,j}$ is then $$\big[A_{i,j}^{(-1)}\big]_{pq} :=[C_{i,j}^{-1}]_{11}\delta_{ip}\delta_{iq}+[C_{i,j}^{-1}]_{12}(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}+\delta_{iq}\delta_{jp})+[C_{i,j}^{-1}]_{22}\delta_{jp}\delta_{jq}.$$

Now we are clear about what exactly $A_{i,j}^{(-1)}$ is, define
$$B:=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i<j}A_{i,j}^{(-1)},\quad P:=\big(\text{diag}(A)\big)^{-1},$$
and $\lambda_{\min}(M)$ to be the minimal eigenvalue of matrix $M$ (with all real eigenvalues).

Random test suggests the following inequality. Is it true in general?
$$\lambda_{\min}(PA)\le \lambda_{\min}(BA)$$

---

It is true for $n=2$.

---

This is an equivalent and simplified reformulation of [a problem in math.exchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582112/minimal-eigenvalue-inequality).

Comment: For $n=2$ are you just saying that $1 \leq \min (\sigma(PA))?$

Comment: @IgorRivin: Yes, but with your inequality direction reversed. Note I just changed symbol for the minimal eigenvalue in my question.

Comment: Why A_ij invertible?

Comment: @M.Lin: $A$ is positive definite, so any of its principal minor should be too and thus invertible. I guess I know why you asked that question. You are right, that $A_{i,\,j}$ per se as defined before is not invertible because of its zero entries. I have edited my question to make it rigorous. Please review.

Comment: Not sure I am interpreting the question (doing the calculations for B) correctly. Is the following $A$ a counterexample?  If so, I also have counterexample for n = 2. Rows are separated by semicolon.

    A =  [ 0.314701883800730   0.142544485540537  -0.127825097123927;
       0.142544485540537   1.878960552501755   1.170389745849448;
      -0.127825097123927   1.170389745849448   0.898912789088150].

$\lambda_{\min}(PA) = 0.341617422975295$

$\lambda_{\min}(BA) = 0.034499626989492$

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: I can not check your n=3 example right now, will later. But can you give your n=2 example, which I doubt is true, first?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure I am calculating correctly.  Here is a fiarly egregious (potential) counterexample for n = 2.  A=[ 0.162437907103227  -0.015486555926447;
  -0.015486555926447   0.153737001687782].
$\lambda_{min}(PA) = 35.948030656167809$
$\lambda_{min}(BA) =   1$

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: P=[1/0.162437907103227, 0; 0, 1/0.153737001687782]. My computation gives $\lambda_{\min}(PA)\approx 0.902$. Can you check your computation?

Comment: Whoops. I carelessly had $PB$ instead of $PA$ on the LHS.  After correcting this, I did not find any counterexamples.

Comment: The definition of the non-zero coefficients of $A^{(-1)}_{ij}$ is still obscure to me. Are they  $1/M_{lk}$, where $M_{lk}$ is the $(lk)$-minor of $A$? (for $(lk)=(ii),\  (ij),\  (ji)$ or $(jj)$, and $0$ otherwise)

Comment: @PietroMajer: It is not the entrywise inverse of $M_{lk}$ but the matrix inverse of $[M_{lk}]$. I have added a detailed and specific definition of $A_{i,j}^{(-1)}$ in the question Please review and.let me know if my definition is clear to you.

Comment: I'm clear now, thank you for your patience

Comment: @PietroMajer: No worries. I appreciate your attention to the question. I would appreciate it even more if you would spend some time pondering the problem and intrigue your colleagues with this problem in order to find a solution.

Comment: Is it the case that $P \preceq B$, or not really (empirically, I mean)?

Comment: @Suvrit: If your inequality refers to the positive definite order, then it does not hold. Consider a nondiagonal $A$ with $n=2$. $x^T\text{diag}(A)x<x^TAx\implies x^TPx>x^TBx$ for either the eigenvector $x$ associated with the maximal eigenvalue either of $\text{diag}(A)$ or $A$.